# Replacing Illegal Characters in a String

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using Javamail to get the FROM address of a message. 
The problem is I always get the following exception.

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string ``ÇáÞÑíÉ ÇáÅáßÊÑæäíÉ''
```

another exception is like

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Nested group in string ``.:DoWnLoAdiZ:.FiLMs <900000009@google.com>'' at position 12
```

How can I format the string before showing it and replace all those illegal white spaces,..etc ?

Comment: Please provide an example of your input. What do you send as "from"?

Comment: Note that since you are quoting the exceptions rather than posting code, you should prefix the quotes with the > character.  This way it will wrap the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are in messages you've received, right?  They're almost certainly spam,
just throw them away.  Spammers are notoriously bad about following internet
standards.

If you really want to try to read these messages, set the System property
"mail.mime.address.strict" to "false", as described in the [javadocs for the
javax.mail.internet package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html).